# Assigning all django models in bulk

Tags: django, django-models

What is the best method of getting dictionary mapping PK into instances of models, like in_bulk() function, but for all objects of given class(model). I want to minimize the number of SQL queries.

Comment: Right. But first, I need to get all pks what takes 1 SQL query. Than I can in_bulk(). But this will generate a huge query. I thought there is something better.

Comment: ah, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dict`, and a list comprehension:

```
model_instances = Model.objects.filter(...)
in_bulk_style_model_instances = dict([(m.pk, m) for m in model_instances])
```

Comment: Don't see the point of the nested list comp. Why not just `dict((m.pk, m) for m in model_instances)`?

Comment: In Python 2.7+ there's a handy dictionary comprehension syntax, which can be much more efficient than dict(): {m.pk: m for m in model_instances}

http://doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2.html

Don't

Comment: It's usually faster to defer to a database though; I don't understand your reluctance, unless your database isn't very good! With a succinct id_list = model.objects.filter(...).values_list('pk', flat=True) followed by a model.objects.in_bulk(id_list), only the PK field is selected and it avoids a huge chunk of Django queryset evaluation, then does what is probably a more efficient dict-comp elsewhere in Django.

Comment: And that's the last I'll say on a three year old question!